# Config attempting to parse: 'System.Net.Http.dll.config'

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, mono

I have made up a Xamarin.Forms project for my company which includes a PCL, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS, and UWP project.
After facing the 65k method limit in Xamarin.Android I enabled Multidex and handled the startup classes in ex.multidex.keep file.
The whole solution is building fine, but when I start the app on my phone (emulator works fine) in debug mode I am facing the following problem:

The build log below shows some kind of reloding / remapping of the System.Net.dll.
When I hit the login button on the app this appears about 20 - 50 times. The app freezes and after about 5 minutes it is working fine again.
I have serval actions which use the System.Net.Http.dll and everytime I have the same problem. The time it takes went from about < 1 s up to > 5s.

> 05-23 09:59:42.879 D/Mono (27301): Image addref
>   System.Net.Http[0x918b6a40] -> System.Net.Http.dll[0x97053600]: 23
>   05-23 09:59:42.879 D/Mono (27301): Config attempting to parse:
>   'System.Net.Http.dll.config'. 05-23 09:59:42.879 D/Mono (27301):
>   Config attempting to parse:
>   '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http.config'.

I implemented Multidex according to the following 2 articles / blog entries:

https://przemekraciborski.eu/2016/09/30/multidex-in-xamarin/
http://www.jon-douglas.com/2016/09/05/xamarin-android-multidex/

I guess this is a Xamaring specific problem because when I first login to my application this happens.
If I logout and try to Login again the time it takes is as it should be (about 2-5 seconds).

I found some other entries in the forum about this but I am not sure whether it is fixed or not or if I did a mistake while implementing Multidex for Xamarin.Android.

Does anybody know about this issue and how to solve it?

Kind regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get rid of those errors you posted by using the android native HttpClient as described here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/http-stack/ Although I am using a shared library, not a PCL like you so I am not sure if it would apply.

Comment: I tried it myself...but I am not able to add the android native HttpClient to my PCL 
Anyways thank's for trying :)

Comment: @Daniel_97 My android app was hanging like yours which is what led me to your post. I have concluded that the issue for me was the Visual Studio 15.2 update in the first half of this month. There was just an update in Visual Studio today that fixed the problem.